# Unable to send an email using PHP mail function on simple HTML page. invalid method verb error

Tags: php, html, azure, email, vs-web-site-project

For some reason, I am unable to get the php to send the email successfully. When I try to run the website on my web server (hosted on azure) it gives me this error "The page you are looking for cannot be displayed because an invalid method (HTTP verb) is being used." Which I believe is an issue with the method parameter in the form, but from everywhere i checked, my syntax is correct.

When I run the site in my localhost and click submit, it proceeds as if it sent the email, but the email never gets sent. Also, yes i did check the spam folder for the email. I removed my email from the code for security.

p.s this is simple html file that I uploaded to an azure web server. I was referred before to a question that had nothing to do with my post before. That post was completely out of scope.

THE Contact form-

```
<div class="contactForm">
                <form action="main_handler.php" method="post" name="form">
                    <div class="row100">
                        <div class="inputBx50">
                            <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Full Name">
                        </div>
                        <div class="inputBx50">
                            <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email Address">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row100">
                        <div class="inputBx50">
                            <textarea
                                name="msg"
                                placeholder="Message">
                                
                            </textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row100">
                        <div class="inputBx50">
                            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
```

The main_handler.php file

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

        $name=$_POST['name'];

        $email=$_POST['email'];

        $msg=$_POST['msg'];



        $to='@mail.com'; // Receiver Email ID, Replace with your email ID

        $subject='Form Submission';

        $message="Name :".$name."\n"."Wrote the following :"."\n\n".$msg;

        $headers="From: ".$email;



        mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)

    }

?>
```

Comment: The syntax of the HTML form is fine. But perhaps the server environment blocks POST requests. Check the config / documentation for that provider.

Comment: @ADyson where would I go to check that? I have my html hosted on azure

Comment: Azure should have some documentation about it. Or at least you can explore within the settings area in your azure portal control panel.